# Wordpress nav menu -- adding conditional span

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, accessibility

Does anyone have a working example of a Wordpress menu outputted manually? The [one on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) didn't seem to work, though my menu_name slug of "Footer" can't be that complicated..? I need to add offscreen spans within external menu links for accessibility purposes. I already have CSS classes; what I need is specific markup added via the functions.php file.

The basic code I'm looking for (see list items w/ 'external' class. Hrefs changed to # for code brevity, they link offsite in real life):

```
<ul id="menu-footer" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="external menu-item">
        <a title="Link opens in a new window." target="_blank" href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions <span class="offscreen">Opens in a new window</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Comments Policy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="external menu-item">
        <a title="Link opens in a new window." target="_blank" href="#">Privacy Statement<span class="offscreen">Opens in a new window</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "...adding conditional span" - how do you determine which list item needs a "external" class?

Comment: The class is added through the menu interface... click on "Screen options" if it isn't visible. I use this in some places to add an external link icon as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the nav menu has to be registered & assigned to the theme for the Codex example to work. DUH!

in functions.php:

```
// default register any navigation menus
register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'footer' => 'Footer Menu',
      'links' => 'Links Menu'
    )
);
```

Assign menu(s) to your theme:

[image: assign a menu to your theme]

Back in functions.php:

```
function accessibleAnchors($menu_name, $link_after = NULL){
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '" class="menu">';

        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
            // uncomment next line to see all array values
            // print_r($menu_item);
            $linkText = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $target = $menu_item->target;
            $titleAttr = $menu_item->attr_title;
            // hard-coding the first & only CSS class here, you could loop through others
            $cssClass = $menu_item->classes[0];

            if($target == '_blank'):
               $titleAttr = " title=\"$titleAttr\"";
               $span = "<span class=\"offscreen\"> Opens in a new window</span>";
            else:
               $span = "";
            endif;

            $menu_list .= '<li class="menu-item '.$cssClass.'"><a href="' . $url . '"'.$titleAttr. '>' . $linkText . $span . $link_after .'</a></li>';
        }
        $menu_list .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $menu_list;
}
```

Now call the function in your template:

```
<?php echo accessibleAnchors('footer'); ?>
```

Boom.

Answer (score 1):

A custom "walker" class?

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Comment: this looks good nate.. a little heftier than i need but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Assuming you've created your menu by using Appearance -> Menus , you can try the following.

1. Navigate to Appearance -> Menus
2. Click the "Screen Options" (top right) of the screen, make sure "CSS Classes" is selected.

Once you've done the above steps, each of the menu items will now have a "CSS Classses" textbox showing where you can on an individual basis assign CSS Classes (have a look at the screen grab).

**Option 2:**

You could also try http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items

```
<?php
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if(is_single() && $item->title == "Blog"){ //Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item->title
             $classes[] = "special-class";
     }
     return $classes;
}
?>
```

**Option 3:**

Provided the above 2 options don't work you have the 3rd option of using jQuery.

HTH

[image]

Comment: I already have a CSS class. What I need is conditional markup inside of the anchor link. I'd rather not do this with JS, otherwise I wouldn't have posted my question

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to start in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php to Copy and paste the function to your theme's functions.php and change the name or use a filter in functions.php to change selected markup of the hook. And possibly take a look in wp-includes/nav-menu.php as well.

Sorry I can't provide more detail.

Comment: Please don't tell somebody to change the core code of Wordpress. This would result in to much problems on updating. Any such changes should be made to the theme. The latter is possible by using the functions.php and appropriate hooks. See the 2011-theme for examples on modifying the menus.

Comment: You should give me a plus one for the one that's possible, resulting in a net gain, of ZERO! :)